# Phing - Pulling from Github Repository

Tags: github, phing

I am trying to use Phing to call git and pull a remote private repository, but it's not working.

Here is my code for Phing:

```
<project name="test" default="main">
    <!-- Get User Variables -->
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <!-- Declare Variables -->
    <property name="base.dir" value="../" />
    <property name="git.repository" value="git@github.com:test/test.git" />

    <!-- Pull Git Release -->
    <target name="git.pull">
        <gitpull 
            repository="${git.repository}" 
            source="origin" 
            refspec="${git.release}"
        />
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="git.pull">
    </target>
</project>
```

But when I run I get this error:

```
You must specify readable directory as repository.
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Or have a working example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `pull` you must give a *local* repository. The remote repository (the one, where to pull from) is the one you give with `source`

You can find examples in the test https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/master/test/etc/tasks/ext/git/GitPullTaskTest.xml

Comment: In that example it uses `gitclone` and the repository is remote. I tried that and I got the same error. The `source` is nothing ever than 'origin'

Comment: You should not stop reading after the first tag. Of course you need a local repository with one remote to _pull_ from somewhere. The tests first clone a remote repository, that will also add cloned repositories url as remote named `origin`. In the next step it pull from it. In gits world the "main" remote is usually named `origin` ;)

Comment: Right -- I copied the entire target, and it errored out on the clone, which is why I mentioned it >.<

Comment: I think there was something wrong with my setup, pretty sure you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Target directory is must exist. But, it's must empty. It is not to include .git directory.